# Given module m and code object c, what does "exec c in m.__dict__" do?

Tags: python, exec

I'm writing Python 3 code and for some reason I want to run everything just in memory and save no files on disk. I managed to solve almost all of my problems so far by reading answers here, but I'm stuck on these lines:

```
>>> code = compile(source, filename, 'exec')
>>> exec code in module.__dict__
```

I don't really understand what the second line does, since I have "in" connected with loops and testing whether something is in some set or not which is not this case.

So, what does the second line do? And what is its Python 3 equivalent since in py3 is exec function, not keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exec code in module.__dict__
```

means execute the commands in the file or string called 'code', taking global and local variables referred to in 'code' from `module.__dict__` and storing local and global variables created in 'code' into the dictionary `module.__dict__`

See http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec

Eg:

```
In [51]: mydict={}

In [52]: exec "val1=100" in mydict

In [53]: mydict['val1']
Out[53]: 100
```

Eg2:

```
In [54]: mydict={}

In [55]: mydict['val2']=200

In [56]: exec "val1=val2" in mydict

In [57]: mydict.keys()
Out[57]: ['__builtins__', 'val2', 'val1']

In [58]: mydict['val2']
Out[58]: 200

In [59]: mydict['val1']
Out[59]: 200
```

Comment: No, it's just the other way round: The scope (locals and globals) are **taken** from `module.__dict__`, not stored to. In other words: They provide the execution context that `code` will be executed in.

Comment: @Lukas Graf - the code snippet I added confirms how it works.

Comment: Yes, never mind my comment. They are obviously read _and_ stored.

Comment: Added an example showing reading as well. Thanks since my original comment implied it only stored variables created by 'code'.

Answer (score 3):

The `in` keyword specifies a dictionary to use for the global and local namespaces. From the python 2 [documentation for `exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement):

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope. If only the first expression after `in` is specified, it should be a dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local variables.

The python 3 equivalent is thus `exec(code, module.__dict__)`.

Comment: Thanks, I would not expect "in" to work this way, it just looks strange to me.

Comment: @user1687327 Note that this is not the same `in` you know from `item in lst`. As part of the [`exec` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) it's simply a string literal that is (an optional) part of the statement. That's different from the [`in` operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in) used to test [containment](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.contains).

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 that exec line would translate to:

```
exec(code, module.__dict__)
```

Excerpts from the Python 3 help files:

```
exec(object[, globals[, locals]])
```

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed
>   in the current scope. If only *globals* is provided, it must be a
>   dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local
>   variables. If *globals* and *locals* are given, they are used for the
>   global and local variables, respectively. If provided, *locals* can be
>   any mapping object.